# Troubles with insert into on PHP and SQLSRV

Tags: php, sqlsrv

I'm trying to make a connection with php 5.4 an sqlsrv, but I don't have much experience about, and my code returns the next error: Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\HOLA\Regis.php on line 50. Where is my error? if someone could help me! :)

```
<?php
$user='sa';
$pass='D3s4rr0ll0';
$srvr='EQUIPO\SQLXPRESS08_DC';
$dbname='USERS';

$info=array('Database'=>$dbname,'UID'=>$user,'PWD'=>$pass, 'CharacterSet'=>"utf-8");
$link=sqlsrv_connect($srvr,$info);

if(!$link){
echo "No se puede ejecutar la consulta";
die( print_r(sqlsrv_errors(),true));
}
if(isset ($_POST['enviar'])){
if(empty($_POST['Nombre']) or empty($_POST['Apellidos']) or empty($_POST['Empresa']) or                                empty($_POST['Email']) or empty($_POST['Contraseña']) or empty($_POST['Recontra']))
{
echo "Por Favor Llene Todos Los Campos Primero";
}

else{
$tsql='SELECT * FROM usuarios';
$rec=sqlsrv_query($link,$tsql);
$verificarUsuario=0;

if($rec==false){
    die(print_r (sqlsrv_errors(),true));
}

while($result = sqlsrv_fetch_object($rec)){
     if($result->Nombre==$_POST['Nombre']){
        $verificarUsuario=1;
     }
    }
    if ($verificarUsuario==0){
        if($_POST['Contraseña']==$_POST['Recontra']){
            $nombre=$_POST['Nombre'];
            $apellidos=$_POST['Apellidos'];
            $empresa=$_POST['Empresa'];
            $email=$_POST['Email'];
            $contraseña=$_POST['Contraseña'];
            $recontra=$_POST['Recontra'];

            $tsql="INSERT INTO usuarios      (Nombre,Apellidos,Empresa,Email,Contraseña) 
            VALUES($nombre,$apellidos,$empresa,$email,(sha1($contraseña));";

            if(sqlsrv_query($link,$tsql)){  
            echo "Registro Exitoso!";
            }
            else{
                echo "No!";
                die('Errores: ' .sqlsrv_errors());
            }

            }
            else{
            echo "Las Contraseñas No Coinciden, Por Favor Intente De Nuevo";
        }

        }


    }
}
```

?>

Answer (score 0):

Looks fine for line 50, but maybe its line 51
Try this for line 51:

`die('Errores: ' .var_dump(sqlsrv_errors()));`

If you still get an error try commenting out lines 50 and 51!

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your answer, I solved my trouble callin a stored procedure, but anyway, thanks!